# Are ReaderInterceptor, WriterInterceptor thread safe?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I want to invoke stateless EJB from `ReaderInterceptor`, `WriterInterceptor` but I'm not sure is this interceptors can I inject EJB or I need every time lookup EJB?

Answer (score 0):

Specification jax-rs 2.0 say nothing about creating instance for each request. So, it's not thread safe

Answer (score 0):

§6.4 of the JAX-RS 2.0 specification states:

> ... a single instance of each filter or entity interceptor is instantiated for each JAX-RS application. ...

Therefore your interceptor is by definition a singleton. However, the injection point for your EJB will consist of a proxy that takes care of providing access to an unused instance of the stateless EJB each time it is invoked. It may find it in a pool of pre-created instances or it may just create and initialise a new one.

Additionally, §4.10.13 "Non-reentrant Instances" of the EJB 3.2 specification states that:

> The container must ensure that only one thread can be executing a stateless or stateful session bean instance at any time. Therefore, stateful and stateless session beans do not have to be coded as reentrant. ...

In summary, just inject your EJB. The container will look after thread safety issues on your behalf.